# Inserting value of column from other table into $criteria as value of column of table of current module

Tags: php, arrays, printing, yii

What I am trying to do:
I want to print data from table using CGridView, yet one important thing - I need to change value of 'bookId' in $criteria to value of 'bookName' from other table.

How can I do that?

regards.

```
/// here comes code from model

  public function search() {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

     $criteria->compare('bookId',$this->bookId);
           $criteria->compare('bookBookdetailId', $this->bookBookdetailId);
           $criteria->compare('bookState', 1);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,

/// here is code from view


print_r($model);
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(), 'columns' => array(
        'bookCatalgoueNumber', 
        'bookDescription',
        'bookBookdetailId'
        ),

        )
);

/// the name of the model is Book, the other is Bookdetail (and so are the tables)
```

/// also bookBookdetailId is foregin key that links to Bookdetail.bookdetailId

// I expect that result will the name of the book (bookdetailTitle) to replace bookBookdetailId

Comment: show your code. It will be better to understand.

Comment: Please post some code so that we will get better idea

Comment: Could you provide more info? Give us an example of what your db design looks like and what you expect as a result.

Comment: added code. and I expect that result will the name of the book (bookdetailTitle) to replace bookBookdetailId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to search/sort by that column, this will probably be the best answer I can give you:

http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/

**UPDATE** (because I'm guessing you didn't really understand the link. Or simply didn't want to read it because it's long..)

I'm assuming:

- You got a relation to your bookdetails table called 'bookdetails'
- You got a column in your bookDetails table called 'name'

Step 1: Add this to your model:

```
private $_name = null;
public function getName()
{
    if ($this->_name === null && $this->bookDetails !== null)
    {
        $this->_name = $this->bookDetails->name;
    }
    return $this->_name;
}
public function setName($value)
{
    $this->_name = $value;
}
```

Step 2: Now add 'name' to the search rule in the 'rules' function of your Book model

Step 3: Change your 'search' function of your Book model to:

```
public function search() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = "bookDetails"; // Make sure you query with the post table.

    $criteria->compare('t.bookId',$this->bookId,true);
    $criteria->compare('t.bookState',$this->bookState);
    $criteria->compare('t.bookBookdetailId',$this->bookBookdetailId,true);
    $criteria->compare('bookDetails.name', $this->name,true);

    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->attributes = array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'t.create_time DESC',
        'bookId'=>array(
            'asc'=>'t.bookId',
            'desc'=>'t.bookId desc',
        ),
        'bookState'=>array(
            'asc'=>'t.bookState',
            'desc'=>'t.bookState desc',
        ),
        'bookBookdetailId'=>array(
            'asc'=>'t.bookBookdetailId',
            'desc'=>'t.bookBookdetailId desc',
        ),
        'name'=>array(
            'asc'=>'bookDetails.name',
            'desc'=>'bookDetails.name desc',
        ),
    );

    return new CActiveDataProvider('Book', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>$sort
    ));
}
```

Step 4: Now add 'name' to your columns array in your CGridView. Should become something like:

```
'dataProvider' => $model->search(), 
'columns' => array(
    'bookCatalgoueNumber', 
    'bookDescription',
    'bookBookdetailId',
    'name',
),
```

Step 5: Read the article to understand what's going on.
Step 6: Enjoy

Comment: I do not have admin as I am creating it from scratch without use of Gii to create me CRUD.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. It explains the complete procedure. If you read it well, you can implement it in your project too. The article has helped many many Yii-ers

Comment: well looks great but still I dunno how do I add value from other table into array to replace the value of bookBookdetailId with the values of bookdetailTitle

Answer (score 0):

Use it in your admin

`array('name' => 'book_id', 'header' => 'Book', 'value'         =>'YourModel::getName($data["book_id"])')`

`getName()` must be your function in your model as follows

```
public function getName($book_id) 
{
    $sql = "SELECT book_name  from `Your Table Name` where `id`='$book_id'";
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $rs = $command->queryAll();
    return $rs;
}
```

Comment: Use AR instead of plain sql to fix your issue where you can. Unless you have some reasons not to...